# If I'm in ViewB, is there a way to call a method in ViewC?

Tags: iphone

I have an app with a view that shows shuffling cards.  The onCreate calls a method called start shuffle.
The next view shows the card the user picked.  It has a button to shuffle again, that calls popViewController to go back to the shuffle view.  After popViewController is called is there a way to call StartShuffle from the ShuffleView?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using UINavigationController and StartShuffle method is in your rootViewController. You can call to this StartShuffle method from ShuffleView with this code:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
YourRootViewController *rootViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];

[rootViewController startShuffle];
```

Comment: Hi StartShuffle is not in the root view, it is in the view , I have 4 views, home, card deck, shuffle, and displaycard.  Is thier a way to do it if its not in the root but in the pre view?